# Lambda function invoked before secrets extension initialized

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-lambda-extensions

I have been trying to use AWS secrets lambda extension to cache secrets from secrets manager. I have been following [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_lambda.html)
for the implementation. If I fetch secrets without adding the cache layer, I am able to get secrets correctly. Once I add the lambda secrets extension and try to fetch the secrets I am getting 400 error.

```
def get_secrets():
    headers = {"X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token": os.environ.get('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN')}
    secrets_extension_http_port = "2773"
    secrets_extension_endpoint = "http://localhost:" + \
    secrets_extension_http_port + \
    "/secretsmanager/get?secretId=" + \
    "my-secrets"
try:
    r = requests.get(url="http://localhost:2773/secretsmanager/get?secretId=sf-secrets", headers=headers)
    secret = json.loads(r.text)["SecretString"]  
    return secret
except Exception as e:
    print(f"""error::::{e}""")
```

Below is the log

```
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL is debug. Log level set to debug.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_CACHE_ENABLED is not present. Cache is enabled by default.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_CACHE_SIZE is not present. Using default cache size: 1000 objects.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG SECRETS_MANAGER_TTL is not present. Setting default time-to-live: 5m0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG SSM_PARAMETER_STORE_TTL is not present. Setting default time-to-live: 5m0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG SECRETS_MANAGER_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is not present. Setting default timeout: 0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG SSM_PARAMETER_STORE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is not present. Setting default timeout: 0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_MAX_CONNECTIONS is not present. Setting default value: 3.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT is not present. Setting default port: 2773.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 INFO Systems Manager Parameter Store and Secrets Manager Lambda Extension 1.0.103
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 DEBUG Creating a new cache with size 1000
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/08/11 07:29:53 INFO Serving on port 2773
response code 400
not ready to serve traffic, please wait
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

[ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
return load_source(name, filename, file)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
module = _load(spec)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/var/task/app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
from app.routers import router as api_router
File "/var/task/app/routers/router.py", line 2, in <module>
import app.constants as constants
File "/var/task/app/constants.py", line 3, in <module>
DATABASE_HOST = str(secrets.get_database_host())
File "/var/task/app/secrets.py", line 79, in get_database_host
return PASSWORDS['username']
EXTENSION   Name: AWSParametersAndSecretsLambdaExtension     
State: Ready    Events: [INVOKE, SHUTDOWN]
START RequestId: 15572c5d-9c3c-4f17-92c8-6b17d854ac93 Version: 
$LATEST
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
END RequestId: 15572c5d-9c3c-4f17-92c8-6b17d854ac93
REPORT RequestId: 15572c5d-9c3c-4f17-92c8-6b17d854ac93   
Duration: 10126.93 ms   Billed Duration: 10127 ms   Memory 
Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 58 MB
```

I have tried by passing in name and ARN as parameters value for secretId in the url but I get the same error.
My lambda function is attached to a VPC and I am using VPCe for connecting to secrets manager.

**lambda execution role has below actions**

```
"secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
"secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
"secretsmanager:ListSecrets",
"kms:Decrypt"
```

Am I missing something in the implementation? As per the docs available, implementation looks pretty straight forward though.

**Steps to replicate:**
I am running a fatsapi application

1. create a directory app and add a file app.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum
from app.routers import router as api_router

app = FastAPI()
handler = Mangum(app)

app.include_router(
    api_router.router,
    prefix="/api/v2"
)
```

2.Create a directory router and add file router.py

```py
import app.secrets as secrets
from fastapi import APIRouter


router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/secrets")
async def get_secrets():
    
    db_host = secrets.get_database_host
    print(db_host)
    return db_host
```

3. In the app directory add another file secrets.py

```py
import json
import requests
import os

def get_secrets():
headers = {"X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token": os.environ.get('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN')}
try:
    r = requests.get(url="http://localhost:2773/secretsmanager/get?secretId=sf-secrets", headers=headers)
    print(f"""response code {r.status_code}""")
    print(r.headers)
    secret = json.loads(r.text)["SecretString"]  
    return secret
except Exception as e:
    print(f"""error::::{e}""")

  
    
    
PASSWORDS = get_secrets()
print(f""""Response from secrets manager {PASSWORDS}""")

def get_database_host() -> str:
    return PASSWORDS['username']

def get_database_password() -> str:
    return PASSWORDS['password']
```

Add requirements.txt

```py
fastapi==0.95.0
uvicorn==0.17.6
mangum==0.17.0
boto3==1.28.3
requests==2.31.0
```

Comment: The current log does not provide information about why it's returning a 400 response. To troubleshoot, set the environment variable `PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL` to `debug`. This will enable detailed logging in CloudWatch, allowing you to identify the actual root cause. If you're still unsure after reviewing the debug logs, then update your question with the debug logs so that others can help you.

Comment: @codeninja.sjI have updated the question with logs from cloudwatch.

Comment: seems the problem lies with your code. Can post the complete Python implementation to reproduce the scenario on my end? because in the above-mentioned code, you didn't specify how/where you defined the get request.

Comment: @codeninja.sj I have edited the question to add the get request.

Comment: I tried your code and was able to retrieve the secret value, so there is no problem with the `get_secrets()` method. The problem exists outside of the mentioned method. Based on the error logs, it seems that it failed while importing the module, so make sure you published all the required modules to the lambda function. To troubleshoot, consider gradually adding functionalities to your lambda function. This step-by-step approach will assist you in identifying the problematic code or module causing the issue within your lambda function.

Comment: @codeninja.sjI tried by moving the code to fetch secrets in the main module. It works fine. But If I move the code to a different module say "moduleB" and then import this in "moduleA". In that case it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code in a new file called custom_mangum.py

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from typing import Callable

from mangum.protocols import HTTPCycle, LifespanCycle
from mangum.types import (
    ASGI,
    LambdaContext,
    LambdaEvent,
)

from mangum import Mangum


class CustomMangum(Mangum):
    app: Callable
    build_settings: Callable

    def __init__(self, app: Callable, build_settings: Callable, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, *args, **kwargs)
        self.app = app
        self.build_settings = build_settings

    def __call__(self, event: LambdaEvent, context: LambdaContext) -> dict:
        self.build_settings()
        api: ASGI = self.app()
        handler = self.infer(event, context)
        with ExitStack() as stack:
            if self.lifespan in ("auto", "on"):
                lifespan_cycle = LifespanCycle(api, self.lifespan)
                stack.enter_context(lifespan_cycle)

            http_cycle = HTTPCycle(handler.scope, handler.body)
            http_response = http_cycle(api)

            return handler(http_response)

        assert False, "unreachable"  # pragma: no cover
```

this code is the similar mangum class but CustomMangum class recive 2 params to init

- function with code to fastAPI project
- function to build parameter with layer

then in the settings.py

```
class Settings:
    USERNAME: str
    PASSWORD: str
    secrets: dict

    def build_secret(self):
        headers = {"X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token": os.environ.get('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN')}
        try:
            r = requests.get(url="http://localhost:2773/secretsmanager/get?secretId=sf-secrets", headers=headers)
            print(f"""response code {r.status_code}""")
            print(r.headers)
            secret = json.loads(r.text)["SecretString"]
            

            # here you can get your secrets environments
            self.USERNAME = secret["username"]  
            self.PASSWORD = secret["password"]
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"""error::::{e}""")

settings = Settings()
```

and in the app.py change your code with this

```
from settings import settings
from custom_mangum import CustomMangum


def get_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    app.include_router(
        api_router.router,
        prefix="/api/v2"
    )
    app.include_router(
        api_router.router,
        prefix="/api/v3"
    )

    return app

handler = CustomMangum(get_app, settings.build_secret)
```

and that's it, good luck